# How to use Primitive API in MessagePack?

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, msgpack

I try to serialize and deserealize like this:

```
 var mem = new MemoryStream();
 MessagePackBinary.WriteInt64(mem, 1580358);
 var result = MessagePackBinary.ReadInt64(mem);` 
 //System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invalid MessagePack code was detected, code:-1'
```

But i have error.
What i do wrong?
Thank you!

Using library: [MessagePack repo](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should rewind the stream to initial position to read back what you wrote there:

```
var mem = new MemoryStream();
MessagePackBinary.WriteInt64(mem, 1580358);
mem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // added
var result = MessagePackBinary.ReadInt64(mem);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```